# Lua - Couple Questions

Tags: lua

Im a amatuer at coding. So, mind me if i face palmed some things.

Anyways, im making a alpha phase for a OS im making right? I'm making my installer. Two questions. Can i get a code off of pastebin then have my lua script download it? Two. I put the "print" part of the code in cmd. I get "Illegal characters". I dont know what went wrong. Here's my code.

```
 --Variables
Yes = True
No = False
--Loading Screen
print ("1")
sleep(0.5)
print("2")
sleep(0.5)
print("Dowloading OS")
sleep(2)
print("Done!")
sleep(0.2)
print("Would you like to open the OS?")
end
```

Comment: You're an "amatuer" programmer, but you're *making an Operating System?* Slow down. If you can't even understand syntactically correct Lua (and that's not syntactically correct), you're a *long way* from making an OS.

Comment: Its a alpha. Plus, i understand that. Im teaching myself step by step.

Answer (score 3):

I see a few issues with your code.

First of all, `True` and `False` are both meaningless names - which, unless you have assigned something to them earlier, are both equal to `nil`.  Therefore, your `Yes` and `No` variables are both set to `nil` as well.  This isn't because true and false don't exist in lua - they're just in lowercase: `true` and `false`.  Creating `Yes` and `No` variables is redundant and hard to read - just use `true` and `false` directly.

Second of all, if you're using standard lua downloaded from their website, `sleep` is not a valid function (although it is in the Roblox version of Lua, or so I've heard).  Like uppercase `True` and `False`, sleep is `nil` by default, so calling it won't work.  Depending on what you're running this on, you'll want to use either `os.execute("sleep " .. number_of_seconds)` if you're on a mac, or `os.execute("timeout /t " .. number_of_seconds)` if you're on a PC.  You might want to wrap these up into a `function`

```
function my_sleep_mac(number_of_seconds)
    os.execute("sleep " .. number_of_seconds)
end

function my_sleep_PC(number_of_seconds)
    os.execute("timeout /t " .. number_of_seconds)
end
```

As for the specific error you're experiencing, I think it's due to your `end` statement as the end of your program.  `end` in lua doesn't do exactly what you think it does - it doesn't specify the end of the program.  Lua can figure out where the program ends just by looking to see if there's any text left in the file.  What it can't figure out without you saying it is where various sub-blocks of code end, IE the branches of `if` statements, `function`s, etc.  For example, suppose you write the code

```
print("checking x...")
if x == 2 then
print("x is 2")
print("Isn't it awesome that x is 2?")
print("x was checked")
```

lua has no way of knowing whether or not that last statement, printing the `x` was checked, is supposed to only happen if `x` is 2 or always.  Consequently, you need to explicitly say when various sections of code end, for which you use `end`.  For a file, though, it's unnecessary and actually causes an error.  Here's the `if` statement with an `end` introduced

```
print("checking x...")
if x == 2 then
print("x is 2")
print("isn't it awesome that x is 2?")
end
print("x was checked")
```

although lua doesn't care, it's a very good idea to indent these sections of code so that you can tell at a glance where it starts and ends:

```
print("checking x...")
if x == 2 then
    print("x is 2")
    print("isn't it awesome that x is 2?")
end
print("x was checked")
```

with regards to your "pastebin" problem, you're going to have to be more specific.

Comment: Im trying to make it where, that it will take a pastebin code, then download the text on to your PC.

Comment: Download what text?  And from where?  By download, do you mean download from the internet (in which case you'd already have to have a server set up), or "download" from a file.  And is this "pastebin" the pasteboard?  IE where the copy/paste text is stored?

Answer (score 0):

You can implement `sleep` in OS-independent (but CPU-intensive) way:

```
local function sleep(seconds)
  local t0 = os.clock()
  repeat
  until os.clock() - t0 >= seconds
end
```

Comment: `os.clock() - t0 >= n` should be `os.clock() - t0 >= seconds` =)